# To add product grid in custom module admin form

Tags: magento, tabs, grid, product

I have created custom module in magento. Its working good. But now my problem is, I want to add product grid to my product list tab.I have found the solution through [this link](http://kuri-su.blogspot.in/).I have created new tab.But when i load that tab, its shows me an error like

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setProdlist() on a non-object in /home/trendyc/public_html/app/code/community/Whole/Cate/controllers/Adminhtml/WhcatalogController.php on line 64**

Mycontroller file's productsAction code here

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('products.grid')
            ->setProdlist($this->getRequest()->getPost('products_prodlist', null));
```

I think, i need to do some modification on layout file. But i can't get what modifications need to do there in layout .xml file.I hope you understand my problem. Please help me guys!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this on cms page:

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

or in phtml use this to display products:

`$this->getLayout() ->getBlockSingleton('ccatalog/product_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml();`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to display products list as grid in custom module tab.

Comment: it displays whole admin page, including admin menu. I need to get only product grid on that tab. what changes will i need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You should create xml for your extension, for ex. design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/my_ext.xml and describe your block  product.list

```
<ext_adminhtml_item_products>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="ext/adminhtml_item_edit_tab_products" name="products.grid"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="products_grid_serializer">
            <reference name="products_grid_serializer">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>products.grid</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedProducts</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[prodlist]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>products_prodlist</reload_param_name>
                </action>
             </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
</ext_adminhtml_item_products>
```